# VeraCrypt analogs that support unsafe shutdown?

Tags: encryption

I am completely satisfied with Veracrypt except for one thing. If you open a Veracrypt volume, write something there or deleting. And then you use unsafe shutdown (for example, using the RESET button on PC. Or at the moment when the electricity was turned off in the apartment. Or pulled out the flash drive with volume without unmounting the volume), then, when you mounting it again, you will notice that the changes did not apply. This applies to both changing files, creating new files, deleting files, moving files.

Are there any programs that allow you to simply encrypt a folder, but which do not have this drawback?
Or is it possible to configure Veracrypt so that data is not lost during an unsafe shutdown?

Bitlocker does not suit me because it encrypts entire disks.
In WinRAR, you can set a password for the archive, but as the number of files in it increases, it will open and change the files / their location longer. The size of the files is also affected. In my case, WinRAR slows down a lot.
Just put a password for the system - not an option, I need a password-protected folder that can be transferred.

Comment: This is more into software recommendations. By the way, isn't this how the file system works? How the volume is formatted? Does it a journaling file system?

Comment: Why are you afraid of encrypting the entire disk? You should be afraid of NOT encrypting the entire disk.

Comment: BitLocker encrypts *volumes*, not disks. Typically this means "physical primary partitions" but it can also mean things like one partition (often the only partition) of a .VHD[X] file. Windows is able to mount VHDs (virtual hard disks) and, if BitLockered, will offer to unlock them when mounted (or later when you try to access them). You can also re-lock them, or just unmount the VHD, whenever you want. In any case, you might want to make sure Windows treats the volume (BitLocker or VeraCrypt) as removable, which disables some write caching, trading performance for consistency.

Comment: Have you tried turning off write caching for the disk the volume is stored on?

Comment: Unless you want your encryption key to be able to be grabbed from RAM, then you may want to use FDE (full disk encryption).
A hard reboot with volumes open will always have the possibility of corruption.

Comment: @user1164394 Your comment makes no sense. FDE is vulnerable to an adversary who can read RAM just as any non-FDE encryption is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was using the FAT32 file system. I created a volume with NTFS file system and my problem was solved.

Comment: NTFS is more resilient than FAT to unclean shutdowns, but you still can't remove the device without first unmounting it unless you want to risk data corruption.

Answer (score 2):

> is it possible to configure Veracrypt so that data is not lost during an unsafe shutdown?

Yes. You can do this by [disabling write caching](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/21904-enable-disable-disk-write-caching-windows-10-a.html). Write caching is a common performance optimization that allows the operating system to report to applications that a write has completed even though it's still in memory and hasn't been sent to the drive. The system will eventually synchronize the write cache with the physical storage medium, but if power is lost before that happens, data can be lost.

Turning off write caching can result in a substantial reduction in write performance.